# How do I test a Selenium automation without restarting the browser each time?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

Suppose I have the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

if __name__ == '__main__':

    def open_YouTube():
        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        browser.get("http://www.google.pl")
        fill_search(browser)

    def fill_search(browser):
        elements = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('input')
        for element in elements:
            if 'what are you looking for' in element.get_attribute('innerHTML'):
                search_box = element
                search_box.get_attribute('value') == 'happiness'



    open_YouTube()
```

Now, supposing I made a mistake or want to change anything in the function `fill_search`, is there a way to test only that function, without running the code from the start and reopening the browser?

For example in my Internet Explorer automations via VBA I have a function that identifies currently open instance of the browser by name or URL. I can run this function and test only the code I want to correct, working on an already open instance of the browser.

Is something similar possible through Selenium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the easy (recommended) way, and the complex way.

Easy:

Just import pdb and experiment with functionality in your browser session. Once you've got everything working as desired, update your code and remove the pdb line.

```
def fill_search():
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  # Experiment in the browser session
        for element in elements:
            element = driver.find_element_by_tag('input')
            if 'what are you looking for' in element.get_attribute('innerHTML'):
                search_box = element
                search_box.get_attribute('value') == 'happiness'
```

Complex:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
session_id = driver.session_id
executor_url = driver.command_executor._url
same_session_driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=executor_url, desired_capabilities={})
same_session_driver.session_id = session_id
same_session_driver.continue_doing_stuff
```

Comment: And what if I want to alter the code below `set_trace` during debugging? The debugger seems to 'remember' the old code.

Comment: You may be misunderstanding how the Python interpreter works. Once you run your script, the text of your .py file is read and interpreted - from that point onward, everything is occurring in memory and your .py file is no longer relevant until you run the script again, so you will have to change the code, save it, and re-run to see the changes.